# Add extra database field to blogengine.net

Tags: blogengine.net

I have added an extra field in the Pages table that I call VirtualPath. This is so that I can have virtual paths to my pages.

In the code I add "VirtualPath" as an extra parameter to the CommandText which means that there will be 14 elements to pick from the database. I duplicate the routine to grep the actual value:

if (!rdr.isDbNull(14))
{

page.VirtualPath = rdr.GetString(14);

}

The problem is that the it never enters the if-statement. When I step the code and I arrive at the !rdr.isDbNull(14)-row and do step-in I see that the DBHelper makes a dispose somehow...

My question is: Is there somewhere else I have to do a change to add an extra parameter like this? Or, does anyone have an idea of what I do wrong. And yes, I have entered values to the VirtualPath-field in the database so it should not be null.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 14 elements to pick from the table, the 14th should be referenced by index 13 (zero-based index).